# How to easily copy a non-mut &[u8] into to a &mut [u8]

Tags: copy, rust, slice, mutability

I want to do some manipulations on a &mut [u8].

In my testing code I have:

```
#[test]
fn test_swap_bytes() {
    let input: &[u8] = b"abcdef";
    let result: &mut[u8] = ?;
    do_something(result);
    assert_eq!(b"fedcba", result);
}
```

How can I easily get a mutable u8 slice in this case? What should I put on the place of the question mark?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the fact that a binary literal knows its size at compile-time. Therefor you can dereference it and store it on the stack. Any let binding can also be a mutable let binding.

```
let mut input: [u8; 6] = *b"abcdef";
```

See [PlayPen](http://is.gd/vm1qCD) for a fully working example

Note that there's no reason to specify the type, I just showed it for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

I would use `to_owned()`:

```
#[test]
fn test_swap_bytes() {
    let input: &[u8] = b"abcdef";
    let result: &mut[u8] = &mut input.to_owned();
    do_something(result);
    assert_eq!(b"fedcba", result);
}
```

Evidently this creates a copy (through an intermediate `Vec`), since the input is immutable.